# read data RS232 without polling

Tags: c++, windows, qt

i read data from `RS232` in a `for loop`.this has no good performance.i want don't have a for loop instead of that there was a thing like event that when data is receiving it fire. is this possible? for example when data is receiving from COM16 event firing.

Comment: If you don;t want to block the main thread you can fire your reading function every 100ms or so.

Comment: @Losiowaty *fire your reading function every 100ms* → that's polling...

Comment: For which platform do you develop?

Comment: for windows. i will do that for linux later...

Comment: @Jean : you are right, sorry, I wasn't in my best thinking shape when I posted it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this project is <strike>being added into Qt 5.1</strike> already in Qt 5!

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtserialport/qtserialport-index.html

The examples show two different ways to get the information out of the Serial port:

This one uses a signal slot connection:

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtserialport/terminal.html

This one uses polling in a loop:

http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtserialport/blockingslave.html

This is a different one, but can do all the same things.  I've used this one before with success.  It has a signal slot available in the examples.

https://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/

Hope that helps.